# How to add custom field to devise forgot my password?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, devise

Let me preface this with I am a Java developer, but my team is developing an SSO microservice for our product in rails so I am learning as I go.

Currently I have it setup to send a confirmation of password reset when a user enters their email into this form:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: password_path(resource_name), html: { method: :post }) do |f| %>
<%= devise_error_messages! %>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="medium-12 small-12">
            <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :email, class: 'field-label' %>
                <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="actions columns medium-12 small-12">
            <%= f.submit "Send", id: "send-button" %>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row text-center align-center">
        <div class="small-8 small-centered columns">
            <br><p id="form-subheading">* For security reasons, we do NOT store your password. We will NEVER send your password via email.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

And it successfully passes through the following function in the `class Users::PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController`

```
# POST /resource/password
def create
 super
end
```

The problem is now we need to add the following `first_name` and `last_name` fields to the form, and authenticate it against the User model before sending form to their email, but it is ignoring those parameters entirely. Clearly I need a check somewhere, but have no idea where to begin.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="medium-5 small-12">
        <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :first_name, class: 'field-label' %>
            <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="medium-6 medium-offset-1 small-12">
        <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :last_name, class: 'field-label' %>
            <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I know they get sent to the backend because the `params[:user]` variable contains the information if I put a `byebug` statement in the function. I am just unsure how to validate the new information in the form.

Any help on building custom fields for this form would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So of course, after looking for an hour I post to SO, and I immediately find what I need in the documentation.

Turns out I needed to:

```
# config/initializers/devise.rb
config.reset_password_keys = [:email]
```

and change it to

```
config.reset_password_keys = [:email, :first_name, :last_name]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your user model you can validate those fields. Something like this:

```
validates :first_name, presence: true
validates :last_name, presence: true
```

After sending the form, in the model they are validated. If the `first_name` and/or `last_name` isn't filled in, it will return to the form. [Read this for more information about rails validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html)

Also in your controller you have to accept the params (if you don't already).

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name)
end
```

In your user controller you probably already have the `def user_params`, just add the `first_name` and `last_name` to it.

after that you can access those params like you normally would. (ex: in the `create` function `@user = User.new(user_params)` and you'll have `@user.first_name`.)